# Method /users/{id}/top-answer-tags is returning wrong results

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, users, api-v1.1

I'm trying the following request: 
(555004 happens to be my user id)

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/555004/top-answer-tags

and I'm a bit confused by the result:

```
{
    top_tags: [
        {
            tag_name: "c#",
            question_score: 253,
            question_count: 6,
            answer_score: 39804,
            answer_count: 7237
        },
        {
            tag_name: "c#"
            question_score: 102
            question_count: 8
            answer_score: 21829
            answer_count: 5581
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

First, I didn't answer any C# question (yet).
Second, the returned values seem like global values (or Jon Skeet's scores) and are not grouped by tag name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.

There was effectively a missing where clause on that route.  Very odd.